# will .NET 4.5.2 code throw exception on <4.5.2 machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.5.2

I want to use the [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx) feature in a asp.net 4.5 web application product we ship to many customers.

However its quite possible that most of the customers don't have 4.5.2 Installed. In this scenario I can either provide an alternative solution or display a message to install 4.5.2.

Is it possible to include 4.5.2 code in this way or will it likely throw an exception on startup if 4.5.2 isn't present?

Comment: Wouldn't be faster to try? You should do such test before deployment to customers for sure. I believe - there will be Windows dialog about required .NET version.

Comment: *However its quite possible that most of the customers don't have 4.5.2 Installed.* How this any different from customers not having .NET 4.5 installed? If you want to run the application, install the dependencies.

Comment: 99.9% of the application only needs 4.5 or less this is a large product and we would like to include a feature for customers who have or want to install 4.5.2. But you cannot assume customers will install a new service pack just because you want them to even if it makes sense. Look at ie8 as a example

Comment: If customers want to use my application then they can install the dependencies. New dependencies coming? Communicate that in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately that reality isn't realistic in my industry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll throw when it tries to compile the method that contains a call to `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` with a `MissingMethodException`.

If you avoid any code paths that might force it to compile such methods, then you should be fine and can gracefully warn the user (after e.g. using reflection to check for the presence of this method) or switch to fallback methods.

It won't automatically throw an exception on startup, unless your startup code includes such a call.

Comment: so i can ship a release which targets 4.5 with 4.5.2 code in it,detect the framework version, but extract away the 4.5.2 code into a code path which isn't run unless the detection succeeds?

Answer (score 0):

.Net will check current .NET installed version on startup. If it less than need it will show dialog window, showing reason and allowing download latest version